# WSO2 running server and application in different machines

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 and web service domain. I created an axis2 service application using wso2 carbon studio under eclipse platform. I installed WSO2 WSAS in the same machine and uploaded this service. based on this tutorial. 
http://wso2.org/project/carbon-studio/1.0.11/docs/esb_proxy_service_sample.html#CreatingaProxyServiceUsingCarbonStudioIDE

and able to see the result in eclipse console. Now I want to run the server in separate machine and get the result in eclipse console. Can any one give solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the server on a seperate machine, and use the IP and port on which the server is running and use that from the client code, in plce of localhost.